# call back is not asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I wanted to create a function where in that i am passing a call back function that callback function should be run later after my other task is done like this

```
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
const asyncfunc = (callback) => {
    callback();
};

asyncfunc(() => {
 let i = 1;
 while (i < 1000) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
  }
});
console.log(3);
console.log(4);
```

I am expecting an output like this :
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
.
.
.
.
1000

But these last two console logs are running after the callback function

Comment: Just to be aware, nothing in this code is async.

Comment: Calling a function that internally calls a function is not async. You have not async features in your code. You should investigate `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` and other async language features

Comment: @DavidLee I don't think that would change anything here